# JS error for JQuery in IE 8.0

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have developed a simple page using JQuery. It works fine in almost all browsers (i.e. Firefox, IE, Chrome) but whenever the page is opened in IE, it prompts Javascript error like,

```
'guid' is null or not an object on line 1834
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I thin it would be helpful if you post enough code for someone to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys for your messages.

The error was on my part. For hover event, I was not passing function for "out". Therefore the handler was passed as undefined in jQuery.event function and that causing error for statement ,

if ( !handler.guid )

written at 1834 line of jquery-1.2.6.js file.

While using I thought that out handler is not mandatory to specify, but I guess I am wrong.

Strangely, FF  / Chrome does not prompt error but IE does :) which is bit different than what it used to be.

Regards,
Jatan

Answer (score 2):

Firefox removed the javascript error indication by default because there are a lot of pages that throw javascript errors. To an average user, the error messages aren't useful - only confusing. If you are a web developer, you should definitely install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using the parentNode or parentElement property? There are some issues with that in IE vs other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, FF / Chrome both report this error but in very silent way. You need to go to Firefox 3.0 Javascript errors dialog to see if is there any error and for Chrome you need to go to Javascript console.

In my view, there should be at least some UI indications (like icon would turn RED), for such errors in FF 3.0 as well as Chrome. In FF 2.0, I guess the icon was turning to RED CROSS if any error is there but it does not happen in FF 3.0 !